# Picking random row from query with an exists where clause seem slow

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to pick a random row from a table with what seems like a simple condition which includes it should be present in another table as well having a specific type.

```
 select * from table1 t1 where type='Other' and exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY) order by random() limit 1;
```

I am trying to cut the selection in the second table short by only picking the first row it finds, I am really just interested if any row in that table exists, so one will do. However the time it took to run didn't change anything really. I've also tried joining the tables instead, that took twice as long it seems. Right now it takes a little over a minute to run, I am trying to cut this down to a few seconds, max 10.

Any ideas? The type could change in the query, it needs to be a generic index, not a specific one for "Other", there are hundreds of types.

Table1 has over +10M rows with unique id's, table2 has +95M.

I have an index on the id's as well as type

```
CREATE INDEX type_idx ON table1 USING btree (type); 
CREATE INDEX id_idx ON table2 USING btree (id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table1_pkey ON table1 USING btree (id);
```

Here is the explain

```
Limit  (cost=297536.80..297536.80 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=68436.446..68456.389 
rows=1 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=1503764 read=299217
I/O Timings: read=199577.751
->  Sort  (cost=297536.80..297586.31 rows=19807 width=51) (actual 
time=68436.444..68456.386 rows=1 loops=1)
    Sort Key: (random())
    Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
    Buffers: shared hit=1503764 read=299217
    I/O Timings: read=199577.751
    ->  Gather  (cost=7051.90..297437.76 rows=19807 width=51) (actual  
time=117.271..68418.453 rows=58327 loops=1)
          Workers Planned: 2
          Workers Launched: 2
          Buffers: shared hit=1503764 read=299217
          I/O Timings: read=199577.751
          ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=6051.90..294407.54 rows=8253 width=43) 
  (actual time=84.291..68358.619 rows=19442 loops=3)
                Buffers: shared hit=1503764 read=299217
                I/O Timings: read=199577.751
                ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on table1 t1  (cost=6051.46..135601.49 
   rows=225539 width=43) (actual time=83.250..24802.725 rows=185267 loops=3)
                      Recheck Cond: ((type)::text = 'Other'::text)
                      Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1119917
                      Heap Blocks: exact=20174 lossy=11038
                      Buffers: shared read=94319
                      I/O Timings: read=72301.594
                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on type_idx  (cost=0.00..5916.13 
   rows=541293 width=0) (actual time=89.207..89.208 rows=555802 loops=1)
                            Index Cond: ((type)::text = 'Other'::text)
                            Buffers: shared read=470
                            I/O Timings: read=33.209
                ->  Index Only Scan using id_idx on events  (cost=0.44..65.15 
  rows=257 width=8) (actual time=0.234..0.234 rows=0 loops=555802)
                      Index Cond: (t2.id = t1.id)
                      Heap Fetches: 461
                      Buffers: shared hit=1503764 read=204898
                      I/O Timings: read=127276.157
Planning:
Buffers: shared hit=8 read=8
I/O Timings: read=3.139
Planning Time: 5.713 ms
Execution Time: 68457.688 ms
```

Here is the explain plan after I changed the type index to also include the id

```
Limit  (cost=305876.92..305876.92 rows=1 width=51) (actual 
time=81055.897..81077.393 rows=1 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=1501397 read=303247
I/O Timings: read=237093.600
->  Sort  (cost=305876.92..305926.44 rows=19807 width=51) (actual 
time=81055.895..81077.390 rows=1 loops=1)
    Sort Key: (random())
    Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
    Buffers: shared hit=1501397 read=303247
    I/O Timings: read=237093.600
    ->  Gather  (cost=15392.02..305777.89 rows=19807 width=51) 
(actual time=87.662..81032.107 rows=58327 loops=1)
          Workers Planned: 2
          Workers Launched: 2
          Buffers: shared hit=1501397 read=303247
          I/O Timings: read=237093.600
          ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=14392.02..302747.67 
rows=8253 width=43) (actual time=73.967..80990.425 rows=19442 
loops=3)
                Buffers: shared hit=1501397 read=303247
                I/O Timings: read=237093.600
                ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on table1 t1  
(cost=14391.58..143941.61 rows=225539 width=43) (actual 
time=73.193..20476.307 rows=185267 loops=3)
                      Recheck Cond: ((type)::text = 
'Other'::text)
                      Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1124091
                      Heap Blocks: exact=20346 lossy=11134
                      Buffers: shared read=95982
                      I/O Timings: read=59211.444
                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on type_idx  
(cost=0.00..14256.26 rows=541293 width=0) (actual 
time=73.552..73.552 rows=555802 loops=1)
                            Index Cond: ((type)::text = 
'Other'::text)
                            Buffers: shared read=2133
                            I/O Timings: read=6.812
                ->  Index Only Scan using id_idx on table2  
(cost=0.44..65.15 rows=257 width=8) (actual time=0.326..0.326 
rows=0 loops=555802)
                      Index Cond: (t2.id = t1.id)
                      Heap Fetches: 461
                      Buffers: shared hit=1501397 read=207265
                      I/O Timings: read=177882.156
Planning:
Buffers: shared hit=29 read=10
I/O Timings: read=4.789
Planning Time: 11.993 ms
Execution Time: 81078.404 ms
```

Comment: 'EXISTS' inherently knows it can stop after finding one row.  So it is unsurprising that giving it permission to do so doesn't change anything

Comment: Something is weird about the scan on id_idx.  Why would that cost out to 65.15?  Also, why would it be `Index Cond: (t2.id = t1.id)`?  Index nodes don't report table-qualified names for columns coming from their own table.  I suspect that in the process of anonymizing this you have mangled something important.  Also, you should VACUUM ANALYZE the table.

Comment: What is the version?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try a combination of columns in your index:

```
CREATE INDEX type_id_idx ON table1 USING btree (type, id);
```

How does this change the query plan?

Comment: Hi, I've added the new explain plan up top after I changed the type index to include the id, if anything it seems to be slower unfortunately.

Comment: Did you drop the old indexes and test?

Comment: yes, I dropped the type_idx and recreated it as suggested, result of the query plan I put above in the description (not enough room in a comment). I understand why you are asking since the plans look the same. I also tried flipping the query around, i.e. to start with table2 and filter on rows in table1 with the Other type. No difference. The inner join is still twice as long if not more.

Comment: Funny thing, if I move the type = "Other" clause to after the exists, the query takes a lot longer, so order obviously matter